# Changing appearance of text using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how the Google search box adjusts the Arial font to look the way it does. What I mean by that is, when I try to use Arial on my site at the same font size it seems much thicker then in Google's search box. As far as I can tell there is no way to adjust the `font-weight` of Arial on Windows. So I was wondering how they get arial to display so thin.

I would like to do this via CSS if possible but other means are ok as well.

Comment: Is that what you are using? `font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;`

Comment: Is http://jsfiddle.net/JSLU8/ what you are looking for?

Comment: have you tried opensans?   http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans

Comment: You should be able to (on Chrome) use the developer tools to inspect and see exactly what CSS properties Google has set on their search box.

Comment: @Gab you got it thanks for the info. If you'd like to answer the question i'll be happy to accept it. And thanks every one else for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JSLU8/1/) what you are looking for?

```
.google-searchbox-arial{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-kerning: auto;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #222;
}
```

Comment: Also Google uses `color: #222;`. So it look "thinner"